# remove chamberlain wall unit

Tags: walls, garage-door-opener

How do i remove below wall unit? I need to replace it with a new one

[image]

Comment: I haven't seen a chamberlain garage door control exactly like that one, however typically with chamberlain/Liftmaster the lighted part (which is the button) is hinged and flips up. Anyway the screws should be behind that big nightlight type button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [this one](http://www.chamberlain.com/clicker-and-accessories/garage-door-controls/multi-function-control-panel) which has a [manual](http://www.chamberlain.com/CatalogResourcesV3/en-us/shared/files/tucmanuals/114A2381.pdf), which says:

> Remove the push button cover by gently prying off the top edge with a screwdriver

Comment: Yep. You can probably just press down on the top of the button with your fingers. They're usually fairly loose.